# How to satisfy Rust borrow checker with this simple code?

Tags: rust

I'm getting a Rust compile error from the borrow checker, and don't know how to fix it.
The code below is simple, and no problem with similar code in C++.

```
fn main() {
    let mut nums = vec![1, 2, 3];
    if let Some(x) = nums.last() {
        nums.push(*x);
    }
}
```

Here is the error：

```
message: 'cannot borrow `nums` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable (4, 9)'
```

Comment: not knowing Rust, it might not like doing nums.last() in the same statement as nums.push() as the value of nums.last() might change when pushing a new entry into nums.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can dereference the reference in the guard clause:

```
fn main() {
    let mut nums = vec![1, 2, 3];
    if let Some(&x) = nums.last() {
        nums.push(x);
    }
}
```

Rust has a powerful pattern matching feature, you can unpack almost everything if you know its type. Check the [Rust pattern matching documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.19.0/book/first-edition/patterns.html).

Comment: Thanks, it works. I thought nums.last() conflicted with nums.push(). Where does Rust document explain the "reference unpack"  in detail?

Comment: @LiLei, I updated the answer, you should take a look at all the pattern matching features rust has (sweet as honey) ;)

Answer (score 7):

When you call `.last()` you borrow `nums` as immutable, as mutating it would invalidate the reference `x` that you hold.   You then call `.push`, which borrows `nums` as mutable.

The problem is that you now have an immutable and a mutable borrow of the same value at the same time, which is against rusts memory safety guarantees (multiple readers **or** one single writer guarantee that you will never have invalid memory anywhere).

```
fn main() {
    let mut nums = vec![1, 2, 3];
    if let Some(x) = nums.last() { // Immutable borrow starts here
        nums.push(*x);             // Mutable borrow starts here
    }                              // Immutable and mutable borrows end here
}
```

The solution would be to lower the scope of the immutable borrow by immediately dropping the reference of its result, as per @DanielSanchez's example:

```
let mut nums = vec![1, 2, 3];
if let Some(&x) = nums.last() { // Immutable borrow starts and ends here
    nums.push(x);               // Mutable borrow starts here
}                               // Mutable borrow ends here
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer is more clear. I just didn't know why the life of the immutable borrow did not end. Now I know the reason is that the returned value of nums.last() is reference. But why "&x" can end Immutable borrow?

Comment: in this context, `&x` actually dereferences `x`. Normally, this would move `x`, but integers implement the `Copy` trait, which means that instead of moving `x` we work with an automatically generated copy of `x`. Us dereferencing `x` destroys the reference returned by `.last()` and ends the borrow it caused.